# Rails - Is it better to use class methods in controller or Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my rails model, i define a class and a method to return me an array of Project names. Now my question is, should I, is it correct to use the Project.names array in my view, or should I generate an array in the controller, and pass with an instance variable.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

...snip...

  def self.names
    Project.select(:name).map {|x| x.name }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From practical perspective, it is always a hard decision where to draw the line between view layer and controller logic. It could be questionable to fill your controller with the likes of:

```
# controller
@project_names = Project.names

# view
<%= @project_names.join(", ") %>
```

Only to use the `@procject_names` in the view.

But keeping that code out from views would give you **later** the opportunity to do this without changing the view:

```
# Controller is updated
@project_names = Project.names

# Show only matching projects
if params[:search]
  @project_names = @project_names.select{|n| n =~ /#{params[:search]}/}
end


# view - still the same
<%= @project_names.join(", ") %>
```

Also, take look at the [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) gem which builds upon the 
[Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and **ViewModel** of the [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) pattern.

With Draper, you can keep even your controllers cleaner and have **multiple** decorators for same object depending on the need (e.g one for web, other for mailer) while still using **same view code** to render output.

Common thing to place in the Decorator is **localized dates** which depend on logged in user, therefore don't fit into view, but would clutter the controller with view-layer logic.

Answer (score 2):

I'll definitely stick to fill the instance variable in the controller. BTW, a word about your code:

```
Project.select(:name).map {|x| x.name }
```

Can be refactored to:

```
Project.select(:name).map(&:name)
```

An this, can be refactored to:

```
Project.pluck(:name)
```

Love Ruby.

Comment: Got to know Project.pluck(:name), (pluck), @Dario, yes you are right, cant stop loving ruby :)

Answer (score 1):

It's generally considered best practice to separate the pulling of data and the display of data appropriately, where the view is responsible for only displaying that data.  I'd definitely say it would be a better idea to generate the array in your controller and pass it in to your view.

MVC is a quite a large topic - for more information check out the Rails Guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: Hmm can I ask you "why?" I always wondered to know the answer but can you develop your point please?